# How to set new keyboard shortcuts in emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I am new to emacs.
Is there a way set new key binding permanent for future use. That is I have a set of key bindings I would like to use in all of my future emacs sessions.

The following command is getting deleted (or forgotten) every time I quit emacs.

M-x global-set-key new key-binding  command

How to save this key binding for future use?

Comment: There are very many guides and useful example if you google "custom emacs keyboard shortcut"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the definitions into your `.emacs` file located in your home directory.

For example, I have the following there:

```
(global-set-key "\M-m" blink-matching-open)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is [covered comprehensively in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html#Init-Rebinding).

Comment: OP's problem is that the setting is not persistent between Emacs sessions.

Comment: I did... I saw all the binding code that was described in the page but missed the first line that links to the init file "you can specify them in your initialization file" while not emphasizing much on it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A number of answers above (and elsewhere on SO) didn't work for me. First, the meta key is referred to by something else in my emacs 24.3.1 with GTK+ version 3.10.7 (on Ubuntu 14.04).

A number of options pre-existing on my `init.el` didn't work.

There options on my `init.el` didn't work (and they include the one in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html#Init-Rebinding)):

(a) `(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") 'comment-region)`
(b) `(global-set-key (kbd "<M-up>") 'comment-region)`
(c) `(global-set-key [(meta up)] 'comment-region)`

Then, I discovered that when I do a `M-x describe-key` and pressed metakey + up cursor arrow, the description said the key was `<s-up>`. I tried this:

(a) `(global-set-key '<s-up>' 'comment-region)`

Which didn't work either.

I then tried:

(a) `(global-set-key [s-up] 'comment-region)`

Which is the only one that worked after I exited the session.

I think a number of things need to be improved for both the emacs manual and the in-editor help with respect to keyboard shortcuts. As a nearly 20-year user of emacs, I can vouch for this. The OP's confusion is legitimate.

Comment: To save yourself frustration, always use `kbd` with the string shown to you by Emacs. Hence `(kbd "<s-up>")`. (1) Ask Emacs what the key sequence is; (2) Use `kbd` with that value.